# How to pass argument in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, controller, routes

This is the routing information for the post route:

```
cacic_uorg_type_excluir:
pattern:  /uorg/type/excluir/{idUorgType}
defaults: { _controller: CacicCommonBundle:UorgType:excluir, idUorgType: null}
requirements:
    idUorgType: \d+
```

This is my controller

```
 public function excluirAction( $idUorg, Request $request )
{
    if ( ! $request->isXmlHttpRequest() )
        throw $this->createNotFoundException( 'page not found' );

    $uorgType = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('CacicCommonBundle:TipoUorg')->find( $request->get('id') );
    if ( ! $uorgType )
        throw $this->createNotFoundException( 'UORG nor found' );

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->remove( $uorgType );
    $em->flush();

    $response = new Response( json_encode( array('status' => 'ok') ) );
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return $response;
}
```

But i keep getting error

```
Controller "Cacic\CommonBundle\Controller\UorgTypeController::excluirAction()" requires that you provide a value for the "$idUorg" argument (because there is no default value or because there is a non optional argument after this one).
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem comes from `Request $request`. Initialize the Request in the excluirAction (don't pass it in parameters). I guess your method is waiting for only one parameters because in your error we can read `[...]there is a non optional argument after this one`.

```
//... Don't forget to use Request at the top of the class
public function excluirAction( $idUorg/*, Request $request*/ )
{
    $request = new Request();
    // Your code ...
}
```

Comment: I've post a comment and deleted it because I'm not sur but maybe in your route you have `idUorgType` as variable and in your method the parameter is `$idUorg`. I don't know if it has an incidence.

Comment: I've done some tests and when I use $idUorgType it returns the error "Page Not Found"

Comment: So you access your Action now ? When I watch your code, that's because it's not an XmlHttpRequest (throw an Exception 'page not found').

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to change your defaults to an empty string, instead of NULL. Also your requirements don't match your default value. Try this:

```
cacic_uorg_type_excluir:
    pattern:  /uorg/type/excluir/{idUorgType}
    defaults: { _controller: CacicCommonBundle:UorgType:excluir, idUorgType: ""}
    requirements:
        idUorgType: (^$|\d+)
```